# openshift - custom domain - ssl certificate error in ie8 and XP

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-8, certificate, openshift

We have a JBoss Cartridges running as a custom alias with a wildcard SSL certificate from RapidSSL. In all modern browsers the pages were correct loaded. But in IE8 under Windows XP there is a certificate error.

After investigating everything I’ve noticed that the browser gets the certificate for *.rhcloud.com instead of my custom one. Is it possible to remove the Default root certificate or is there another configuration Option?

Comment: As Steffen stated, Windows XP's `Schannel` provides TLS, but it does *not* utilize Server Name Indicator (SNI) (SNI is a TLS extension). For SSL fallback and non-SNI fallback, you need a single certificate with all the domains hosted for that server. Unfortunately, I think someone's got a patent on that idea (I think its Cisco or Akami). Its amazing what the US will allow to be patented...

Answer (score 3):

You have probably multiple certificates behind the same IP address. To make use of this the client has to support SNI (Server Name Indication), where it sends the servers name inside the  SSL handshake. IE8 or lower on Windows XP or lower do not support SNI and will probably never do. Thus the server does not know, which certificate it should use and uses the default certificate for the IP address.

If you insist on using Windows XP (end of live) you need to use other browsers (Firefox supports SNI) or you need to switch to a service, where you have a single certificate per IP address.